# How can I get a string's length in Java without String API methods?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String length without using length() method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910336/string-length-without-using-length-method-in-java)

I need to get the length of a string (no of characters present) in Java using a `for` loop and without using any methods like `length()`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class reversestring

{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws IOException

    {
     String s;
     int i=0,j=0,k=0;
     DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter ur string : ");
     s=in.readLine();
     char ar[]=s.toCharArray();
     System.out.println("Length of the string is : ");

     for(j=ar[i];j!='\0';i++)
     {

         k++;

     }
     System.out.println(+k);
    }
}
```

I wrote this program, but I am not getting the answer. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Java `String` objects are **not** 0-terminated!

Comment: As you "cannot" use `length()`.. should this be tagged "homework" ?

Comment: @Nanne: according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) the homework-tag (together with other meta-tags) is discouraged.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910336/string-length-without-using-length-method-in-java/2910357#2910357

Comment: Ha, ha, ha, ha ... ! Sorry, sorry, thousand apologies. Could not resist the humour.

Comment: Not a real question. You check the length of a String in Java using the length() method, and there is no defensible reason to do it any other way.

Comment: @joachim-sauer : That's not what I read in that link; it's about how to _respond_ to those questions. I was suggesting it, because it would help understanding the question: otherwise I'd ask to specify why `length()` couldn't be used. If there is some strange reason for that, we might need to take that into account too. But as it is probably homework, we can just take it as a given. So it's not "becasue I don't want to answer that!" but more "what is going on?". See other comments :D

Answer (score 6):

This has been asked before. Here's my favorite answer:

```
str.lastIndexOf("")
```

(which probably even runs in constant time, as opposed to the other answers.)

Answer (score 5):

The following `.length` is not a method.

```
int length = s.toCharArray().length
```

Comment: nor is it a property of the String API. Great workaround.

Comment: What's the "String API"? Why wouldn't `toCharArray` be included in that definition?

Comment: You can't access the String without using the API, unless you use reflection to get the `length` field.

Answer (score 1):

Java isn't C, thus you can't treat Java strings as C strings and you can't expect C methods to work in Java. In particular, Java strings aren't null-terminated.

The 'correct' way would be to use `length` (either a string method, or an array property), but, since you don't want, you could employ 'for each' loop.

```
for (char c in charArray) {
    ++count;
}
```

It feels not good, though.

Comment: The task itself is completely meaningless in the first place, which makes it pretty impossible to give a "good" answer. Having said that: this only hides the `.length` behind some syntactic sugar ;-)

Comment: @Joachim I completely agree, I would never let this code pass review, let alone use it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

a functional guy would answer

```
len(str)
   return str.isEmpty() ? 0 : 1+len(str.substring(1));
```

Comment: why +1? I was being sarcastic...

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter;
String s = "something";

try{
    for(counter=0; s.charAt(counter); counter++);       

}catch(Exception e){
   //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
   System.out.println("Length: " + counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Java's String.toCharArray() returns an array that is not null-terminated, so looking for a null character would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe all the other answers are using the String API, although the title of this question indicates that's not allowed :-P

I came up with this:

```
System.out.println(new StringReader("stackoverflow").skip(Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that StringReader is using the String API behind the scenes. You are simply delegating the use of the API to it.