# How to calculate a length of array with out using library

Tags: java, arrays, string, string-length

yesterday I appeared in interview,interviewer told me to write a code for calculating a length of array with out using a length property of Array class.

For examaple-

```
char[] array=new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray();
// i have to write a code for calculating length of this array
//I can use any operator but use of library is restricted
```

All answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910336/string-length-without-using-length-method) are using String library.

Comment: in language like `c` we use while loop matched it with newline character `\n` to break but how is done with object.

Comment: use a try catch until you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception?

Comment: @Gosu. Appriciated  yes i am also tried this, but this is not a good coding style to detrmine result by exception.

Comment: I hope there is a better way to do this (try/catch seems stupid indeed).

Comment: @gosu how does Array class evaluated its length property? since this `.class` file not available with src?

Comment: You can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/where-is-arrays-length-property-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[] array = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray();
int count = 0;
for (int i : array) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: childish....great `for each loop` is simplest solution of this.very funny.why this not strict to us so far ,good job man.

Comment: In this case: The `length` property is used in the bytecode level: `arraylength`

Comment: @gontard thanks for giving such info,but should be expected since this is done by jdk not by us.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians yes i guess.

Answer (score 2):

A nicer solution might be to use the method: [`java.lang.reflect.Array::getLength`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength-java.lang.Object-)

For example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class ArrayLength {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] array = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'};
        System.err.println(Array.getLength(array));
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please show me a code how to use reflection API since i am unaware of reflection.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians I have added a small example

Comment: this is good to know `reflection API` but for answers perspective this is meaningless since APIs are restricted.

Comment: APIs are restricted ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    char []c = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int i = 0;
    int l = 0;
    try{
    while(c[i++] != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(c[i-1]);
        l++;
    }
    }catch(Exception a)
    {};
    System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion in the comments, which is definitely not good practice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter something: ");
        char [] charArr = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();

        int i = 0;
        try {
            while(true) {
                char c = charArr[i++];
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }

        System.out.println("Length: " + (i-1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter something: Banana
Length: 6
```

Comment: The bad practice is to not use the length property. This interviewer question is stupid.

Comment: @gontard Sometimes they just like to come up with trick questions? I mean it's not impossible to find the length without the length property after all.

Comment: @gontard Interviewer never be stupid,I think he was trying to know at what level of height u can think,idea was not to get a code for coding perspective.this was test of thinking outof box.

Comment: I didn't say the interviewer is stupid only its question... I think this kind of question doesn't help to recruit a good dev.